# Determining whether a graph is planar?

Tags: combinatorics, planar-graphs

Question: If a connected planar graph with n vertices all of degree 4 has 10 regions, determine n.

I am a bit confused about how exactly to handle this problem.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Hint: Use [Euler characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the conditions you have given, we have

$$4|V(G)|=2|E(G)|$$ and $$ |F(G)|=10.$$

Euler's formula for planar graphs tells us that $|V(G)|-|E(G)|+|F(G)|=2$.

Hence $|V(G)|=8$.

By the [plantri](https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/plantri/) package, we get a unique 8-vertex 4-regular planar graph, as shown below. It has $10$ faces, as you would expect. **But why is there only one?** I think there should be a better theoretical proof. (I hope to see it.)

[image]